# Sones GraphDB Query Returning Error

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, sones

I am following their tutorial here:

http://developers.sones.de/wiki/doku.php?id=quickreference:fiveminuteguide

But when I copy and paste this command in webshell

```
CREATE VERTICES 
   ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name),
   University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<Student> Students),
   City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<University> Universities),
   Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Integer Age) BACKWARDEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt)
```

The output generates error:

```
GraphDB@localhost [gql-mode] > CREATE VERTICES ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name), University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<Student> Students), City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<University> Universities), Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Integer Age) BACKWARDEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt) {   "query": "CREATE VERTICES ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name), University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Students), City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Universities), Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Integer Age) BACKWARDEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt)",   "result": "Failed",   "duration": [
    0,
    "ms"   ],   "warnings": [],   "errors": [
    {
      "code": "sones.GraphDB.Errors.Error_GqlSyntax",
      "description": "Syntax error in query: [CREATE VERTICES ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name), University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Students), City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Universities), Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Integer Age) BACKWARDEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt)]\n\n gql: [Syntax error, expected: index,types,abstract,type,]\n\nAt position: 1, 8"
    }   ],   "results": [] }
```

instead of this expected result:

```
{
  "query": "CREATE VERTICES ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name), City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Universities), University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET Students), Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Integer Age) BACKWARDEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt)",
  "result": "Successful",
  "duration": [
    660,
    "ms"
  ],
  "warnings": [],
  "errors": [],
  "results": [
    {
      "DBType": "Entity",
      "UUID": "f1cf505d-3dc9-4ec0-b777-ca1c0075d835",
      "REVISION": "20102110.124020.0492167(8edd08775ce5754581140b203163f93d)",
      "EDITION": "DefaultEdition"
    },
    {
      "DBType": "City",
      "UUID": "89dc4d40-2046-4c0b-8599-6c0665ae62a5",
      "REVISION": "20102110.124020.1952135(8edd08775ce5754581140b203163f93d)",
      "EDITION": "DefaultEdition"
    },
    {
      "DBType": "University",
      "UUID": "274f1216-7ba0-409d-b466-668157b2a6ee",
      "REVISION": "20102110.124020.3592086(8edd08775ce5754581140b203163f93d)",
      "EDITION": "DefaultEdition"
    },
    {
      "DBType": "Student",
      "UUID": "7dec86d3-c62d-49cc-840a-93203bb821dc",
      "REVISION": "20102110.124020.5402167(8edd08775ce5754581140b203163f93d)",
      "EDITION": "DefaultEdition"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what's the problem (I used THEIR OWN lastest binary version I didn't even compile it by myself).

They don't even have a forum :(.

Comment: There is an opensource version that is free as far as I can see. I want .NET not java. db4o is not same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples on the site is out of date. I've heard that Sones GMBH (Creators of SonesDB) is out of money, so the product may be dead.

The correct query of that sample for SonesDB 2.0+ is:

```
CREATE VERTEX TYPES
       ABSTRACT Entity ATTRIBUTES (String Name),
       University EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<Student> Students),
       City EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(SET<University> Universities),
       Student EXTENDS Entity ATTRIBUTES(Int32 Age) INCOMINGEDGES(University.Students StudiesAt)
```

There is no more statement "CREATE VERTICES", now it's called "CREATE VERTEX TYPES"

Integer type - Int32

BACKWARDEDGES - INCOMINGEDGES

CheatSheet for SonesDB 2.0+ you can see [here](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sones/sones/GQL_cheatsheet_latest.pdf). As I see, there is correct information.