# Why is there only ONE NoSQL Platform in .NET vs dozens in Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net

Here's a list
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_storage

I can only see one for .NET (and it doesn't even work as expected ! [Sones GraphDB Query Returning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983455/problem-with-getting-started-on-sones-graphdb-nosql-db-engine-for-net))

Is it because .NET just don't get it yet ?

Comment: Because the .NET one is **perfect.** :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net

Comment: Don't always trust Wikipedia ;)

Answer (score 5):

That comparison table shows the language the project was implemented in, which does not (necessarily) restrict the platform it can be used on.

For example, MongoDB is implemented in C++, but has native-language [drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) for C#, Python, Ruby, Javascript, etc.